# Menu items when you press on right click is not working

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office365-apps

I am using SharePoint on Office 365. I have a problem when i select a document and press on right clic the menu items doesn't appear.

for example here when i go to Documents and select any document and make right click it shows me the menu items which contains share, rename, delete, properties...

[image]

But here when i go to Engineering Projects and choose any documents and press right click so it doesn't show me that menu items like on the previous view.

[image]

how to resolve this problem please ? thank you very much.

Comment: Select the default view and try. I suppose the current view select the title item with no menu

Comment: @Max when i go to Home i find there Documents and Engineering projects together and the right click works. But if press on Documents and make right click on any document works but when i press on Engineering Projects and make right click on any document it doesn't work. i want to make it work like with Documents. any idea please ?

Comment: See this [MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9) and re-read my comment

Comment: You need to modify your view to ensure that you have the column "Name(linked to document with edit menu)" displayed. Your 1st screenshot has this column in the view, because you can see the ellipsis "...", but in your 2nd screenshot it is not there, thus you do not have the menu available.

Answer (score 1):

The right click menu will only display if you have the `Tabular View - Allow individual item` checkboxes ticked.